# Restarting the app to free up heap memory

Tags: android, android-intent, application-restart

At particular point of time in my app, I want to restart the app completely i.e. killing the process associated with the app and then restarting it again. I want to do this to free up heap space as my app contains lot of bitmaps.

I used [this SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6609414/howto-programatically-restart-android-app) with the highest voted answer and created following extra activity as following:

```
/** This activity shows nothing; instead, it restarts the android process */
public class MagicAppRestart extends Activity {
    // Do not forget to add it to AndroidManifest.xml
    // <activity android:name="your.package.name.MagicAppRestart"/>
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        System.exit(0);
    }
    public static void doRestart(Activity anyActivity) {
        anyActivity.startActivity(new Intent(anyActivity.getApplicationContext(), MagicAppRestart.class));
    }
}
```

and calling this activity as `MagicAppRestart.doRestart(this);` from the required place in another activity.

Now, the issue is this works fine on android 2.3 but on 4.0, this code only exits the app but **do not restart it**.

Am I doing anything wrong? Is there exist a solution for this issue which will work on all OS?

Also, I have already tried following code, it restarts the but not process and hence does not free up the heap, so it is of no use to me:

```
Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage( getBaseContext().getPackageName() );
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
```

Any help appreciated !

### Edit

I have 7 activities in my app including home activity. Barring home activity, other 6 activities use `ViewFlipper` with 5-8 screens.

I'm using *unbindDrawables()* in `onStop()` and `onDestroy()` of every activity but it releases only little portion of the memory.

Hence I'm looking to completely restart the app process.

### Edit 2

I just came across this:

*In addition, Android changed the way bitmap memory is allocated. Prior to Android 3.0, bitmaps were allocated in native memory, with only a small descriptor kept on the Java heap; now the entire bitmap is allocated from the Java heap. This can lead to the Java heap being used up very quickly if multiple bitmaps are kept in memory.*

I guess this is the reason why my approach is working in device with 2.3OS and not on device with 4.0 OS.

Comment: Why you want to restart your app`, maybe we can help you to do a other approach

Comment: as mentioned in question: *to free up heap space as my app contains lot of bitmaps*...

Comment: @GAMA Call `bitmap.recycle()` before destroying activity. It would help

Comment: If you are working with images, also have a look at this: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: I'm setting bitmaps from xml and not from java class

Comment: Please check edit in the question.

Comment: @GAMA do you run into memory leaks is your application running slow?

Comment: It's not running slow, but used heap keeps increasing gradually as seen from eclipse. At one point I did faced **bitmap.outofmemory** exception. I added `android:largeheap=true`. Now app don't crash but still heap consumption is the same.

Comment: @GAMA GC kicks in when needs to free memory. Did you try scaling your image down. Also i see no reason fro you quit and restart

Comment: @GAMA for android 3.0 and below use `bitmap.reccyle()` check this http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html. Do not use `System.gc(); Runtime.getRuntime().gc()`.

Comment: I'm using `System.gc(); Runtime.getRuntime().gc();` in onStop() and onDestroy().

Comment: How do I use `bitmap.reccyle()` since I'm setting bitmaps from xml and not from java class

Answer (score 1):

You should not call `System.exit(0)`. It is a bad idea to quit and restart your app.

Quoting Romain Guy from https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/G_D3pKnGLt0

(Romain Guy): The user doesn't, the system handles this automatically. That's what the activity lifecycle (especially onPause/onStop/onDestroy) is for. **No matter what you do, do not put a "quit" or "exit" application button. It is useless with Android's application model. This is also contrary to how core applications work**.

To know more check the below link

[Is quitting an application frowned upon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon)

You should code in such a way that you don't run into memory leaks.

Managing Bitmap Memory

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html

Also check this link on Memory management

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk

Edit:

You can bind the drawable in `onResume` an unbind in `onPause`.

Comment: I know, `System.exit(0)` is not the best practices in android. but if the requirements demands something like this, I have to use it, I guess. Also, I have already checked for memory leaks. It's just that there are lots of bitmaps.

Comment: @GAMA you should rethink your design rather than using `System.exit(0)`. It is not recommended. recycle bitmaps and do check the second link for the same

Comment: @GAMA `recycle` them.  Restarting your app is not a good solution.

Comment: I'm setting bitmaps from xml and not from java class

Comment: @GAMA you can remove them in `onPause` and recycle them when not in use

Comment: Then `finish()` your activity and see this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395068/unbinding-drawables-onpause-causing-unresponsive-back-navigation-and-skipping.  It will allow GC to clear the heap.

Comment: @GAMA pls check link 2 and 3 go through it and re think your design. binding and unbinding the drawable is fine. unbind in `onPause` and bind again in `onResume`.

Comment: regarding **unbind in onPause and bind again in onResume**, I don't have any issue till I'm in the activity. so any solution should be used in onStop() and onDestroy()...

Comment: @GAMA you are free to do whatever you want. Sorry off the op of my head. You should unbind in `onPause`.

Comment: I didn't mean that way dude. I was just trying to go with the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You can't clear the heap. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9798907/how-to-empty-or-clear-heap-memory-dynamically-in-my-code) for better understanding.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have tested that restarting the application process clears the app as you are completely killing the running instance of the app.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It works for me:

```
Intent it = new Intent();

it.setComponent(new ComponentName(YourActivity.this.getPackageName(),YourActivity.class.getName()));
it.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
YourActivity.this.getApplicationContext().startActivity(it);
```

Answer (score 0):

After suggestions from some people, I concluded it's not ideal/recommended to exit/restart the app through code when the app is running.

So, what I have done is - set a flag to identify home button click i.e.exit of app

At that time, I call `android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());` to completely kill the process of current app and to avoid running of app in background.

Thanks all !

Answer (score 0):

Try the top voted answer of Oleg Koshkin in this [how to programmatically "restart" android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6609414/how-to-programatically-restart-android-app) . Hope this will help you.

```
Intent mStartActivity = new Intent(context, StartActivity.class);
int mPendingIntentId = 123456;
PendingIntent mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,  mPendingIntentId,    mStartActivity, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
mgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + 100, mPendingIntent);
System.exit(0);
```